# Prove series of functions $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $f(x) = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x^n\over n}$, suppose we know that $f$ is convergent on $[0,1)$, prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1)$

My attempt:

Since $f(x)$ is convergent, we only need to prove that the derivative of the partial sum, denoted by ${Sn}^{'} = \Sigma_{k = 0}^{n-1}x^k$ is **uniformly convergent** to $g(x) = \Sigma_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^k = {1\over 1-x}$ on $[0,1)$

However, I am stuck trying to use the Weierstrass-M test to prove the uniform convergence. Consider terms in ${Sn}^{'} $, i.e., $x^n$, we know that $x\in [0,1)$, but we can't choose $M_n = 1^n = 1$ or that $\Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty}M_n$ diverges.

What should I do, or are there other ways to tackle this problem?

Comment: You don't need an estimate on the whole $[0,1)$, but an estimate on $[0,\rho)$ with $\rho$ larger than the point you want differentiability at will suffice.

Comment: Check this -> https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243383/399263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is *not* uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$. But it is uniformly convergent on $[0,r)$, for every $r\in(0,1)$. So, if $x\in[0,1)$, take $r\in(x,1)$ and then, since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,r)$, to which $x$ belongs, the restriction of $f$ to $[0,r)$ is differentiable at $x$, and therefore $f$ is differentiable at $x$.